# Undirected graph simple cycles and 3D shapes

Tags: 3d, graph-theory

I have a 3d object made up of vertices and faces. A cube here.
[image: Cube]

I can represent it as a planar undirected graph joining the vertices.
[image: Graph]

Now I'm looking at reconstituting the faces from the 2d graph itself.
My intuition is to look at the simple cycles in the graph and keep the ones representing coplanar vertices.
ie:

- Cycle 0 V0,V1,V4,V7
- Cycle 1 V0,V7,V6,V3
- Cycle 2 V1,V2,V5,V4
- Cycle 3 V7,V4,V5,V6
- Cycle 4 V0,V1,V2,V3

[image: Cycles]

But this method totally misses the back face of the cube.
I realize now, that the back face (V2, V3, V6, V5) is actually the circumference of the graph, or rather the sum of all the simple cycles.

Will this always be the case for any 3d drawing ? Are we sure we'll get all the faces this way. Sorry if it's a bit vague, but I'm looking for an insight I'm missing here in this 3d model / graph duality.
Also can you point me to an algorithm to find this back face ? How would I sum cycles to find this one ?

Comment: After some more research, I now realize that the set of simple cycles depends on the planar embedding of the graph. I'm still left wondering how can I find all the 6 coplanar faces of the cube here from the graph above in memory in a way that can be generalized to more complex objects

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185666/find-all-faces-in-a-graph-from-list-of-edges
Right, I think that's what I'm looking for, it's more complex than I thought.